# Wordpress Видимость страницы "Личное" убрать из заголовка

Tags: wordpress

На странице установлено значение видимости как "Личное"
На сайте, когда отображается заголовок страницы, он выглядит так - "Личное: заголовок страницы" 
Вопрос: Как убрать слово "Личное" из заголовка, не меняя это значение на странице.

Comment: Я бы не стал этого делать - пост виден только автору и может возникнуть недопонимание при общении с другими или при обращении за помощью. Ну а так можно хоть в css скрыть - всё равно это никому больше не доступно.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте такой код в functions.php:

```
function private_title_format_770678() {
    return '%s';
}

add_filter( 'private_title_format', 'private_title_format_770678' );
```